# deploying flask app with uwsgi and flask-script Manager

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, flask-script

Traditionally, I have configured the UWSGI configuration file to call an application like below:

```
mydirectory/uwsgi_application.ini
...
#python module to import
app = run_web
module = %(app)
callable = app
...
```

,

```
mydirectory/run_web.py
from ersapp import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

,

```
mydirectory/ersapp/__init__.py
...
app = Flask('ersapp')
...
```

But now, I am following Miguel Grinberg's Flask book and here he uses an application factory like below

```
mydirectory/ersapp/__init__.py
...
def create_app(config_name):
    webapp = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    return webapp
```

with a "manager" (see [flask-script Manager](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/))

```
mydirectory/manage.py
from webapp import create_app
...
webapp = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
manager = Manager(webapp)
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

In this configuration, I trigger my development server with `$ python manage.py runserver`

whereas before I triggered it with `$ python run_web.py`

Now, I am struggling with what to put in the uwsgi configuration file to allow this app to be deployed via UWSGI. Specifically, the `app`, `module`, and `callable` variables.

The error I am getting in my logs is:

```
...
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't use Flask-Script with uWSGI.  You point it at the app directly.  Or in your case, you point it at a call to the app factory.  The simplest example is:

```
uwsgi --module 'myapp:create_app()'
```

Answer (score 10):

I am also using the `flask-script` manager , so what i did was

- created a `wsgi.py` .which was like.

  `from app import *
  application = create_app("development")`
- then `uwsgi --wsgi-file wsgi.py --callable application`

Note: the callable is the flask object name in the `wsgi.py`.